# How to pass the data to a template using blaze-layout render?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, kadira

I tried the following code to pass data to a template  and receive it in `onCreated()` but I cannot access the data.

```
deviceInfo.js:
BlazeLayout.render('layout',{main:'deviceInfo',stats:'paramstats',attr:"SOME_DATA"});

deviceInfo.html:
{{>Template.dynamic template=stats data=attr}}

paramstats.js:
Template.paramstats.onCreated( () => {
    console.log("onCreated");
    console.log("Data is:",this.data.attr);
});
```

But I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined`.
where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where do you call `console.log("Data is:", this.data.attr);`? please include the full code

Comment: i am calling it in the oncreated of the paramstats template.

Comment: In this instance it would be best to pull whatever data you need directly on the paramstats template. If you need something to tell you about the route, you can rely on FlowRouter.getParam() or FlowRouter.route which will tell you where you're at. Full code/more details will make this easier to answer :)

Comment: I don't want to show the parameter in the url(for  FlowRouter.getParam()) and i also don't want to route to a new page. So, i just want pass data to paramstats template(which is a child of deviceInfo template) from deviceInfo template.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the normal function syntax for `onCreated` callback. Arrow function will bind the context of your function to the outer scope automatically, it is the cause of your problem. Try this:

```
Template.paramstats.onCreated(function() {
    console.log("onCreated");
    console.log("Data is:",this.data.attr);
});
```

Comment: I tried your code,  but it didn't work.
it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined.`

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` to see what it refers to

Comment: This is the best i could do.
`Blaze.TemplateInstance {view: Blaze.View, data: undefined, firstNode: null, lastNode: null, _allSubsReadyDep: T…r.Dependency…}`.
data is undefined. It refers to paramstats template.

Comment: Not sure what is happening to your code. These are something I notice: `firstNode` and `lastNode` is null, don't you have any elements inside your template? `data` is `undefined`, at least it should be the data of its parent unless you override it. Finally try `console.log(this.view.name)` to see if it is really your template

Comment: In onRendered() of deviceInfo.js I was not passing the `attr`. So  it gave `attr` was undefined.  Its a silly mistake, its working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Meteor 1.4.# and I was able to retrieve the parameters like so:

```
BlazeLayout.render("page", { 
    params: ['fullscreen', 'route']
});

// page.js

Template.page.onCreated(function() {
    let params = this.data.params();
    console.log(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you're using two levels of indirection. `BlazeLayout.render()` is giving you one level and then you're using a dynamic template within that? Why not directly render the template you ultimately want using `BlazeLayout.render()`?

In any case, you're dereferencing your data context indirectly.

In the `BlazeLayout.render()` call you're setting the `attr` variable to some value.

Then in your dynamic template you're using `data=attr` but this means that inside your template helpers that `this` is going be have the value of `attr`. There will be no `data` subkey added automatically.

You don't show the value that you're setting for `attr` so it's not even clear that you have an `attr` subkey in your `attr` variable, that would also be confusing to anyone else who ever tries to debug your code.

@khang is correct about not using the arrow function syntax in `onCreated()`, try:

```
Template.paramstats.onCreated(function(){
    console.log("onCreated");
    console.log("Data is:",this);
});
```

`this` should have whatever value you stuffed into `attr` in your `BlazeLayout.render()`